# I am using recursion to test whether not a word is a palindrome. A palindrome is a word that is the same backward ex: race car

Tags: python, recursion, built-in

Why am I getting an error builtin_function_function_or_method object is not subscriptable and how can i make a string into a list so I can index into the string?

```
s = input("Please enter a word: ")
s = s.lower
Pal = True
def recpal(s):
    if Pal == False:
        return(False)
    else:
        return(True)

def main():
    y = recpal(s)
    first_char = 0
    last_char = -1
    if s[first_char] != s[last_char]:
        print("It is not a Palindrome")
    i = 0
    while i >= n[-1]:
        first_char = first_char + 1
        last_char = last_char -1</i>





main()
```

Comment: `s = "amanaplanacanalpanama"; s == s[::-1]`

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is this line:

```
s = s.lower
```

Here you are assigning the method (or function) `s.lower` to `s`, overwriting the original string. At this point you have lost what the user typed in. You get the error because you can't use the `[]` notation with a function, which you try to do with e.g. `s[first_char]`.

More than likely you intended to *call* the function and keep its return value, a lower-case value of the original string, in `s`:

```
s = s.lower()
```

There are many other problems with your code but that is the one that's causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

You mean to do, in line 2:

```
s = s.lower()
```

There are more problems after that, but the specific problem you are having is that you are not calling the function (you need the parentheses).